# Hashmap, Sort/Duplication issue

Tags: java, sorting, duplicates

Well, I need one more problem to be fixed.  My hashmap code adds/removes/modifies/prints/sorts(somewhat).  It's the sorting issue.  It sorts by last name in ascending order.  If two employees have the same last name, then it proceeds to ascends by first name.  The problem though, is if the two employees has the same first name as well, then it has to sort by ID number, which does not.

My code: If two employee have the same full name but different ID number, then it only prints out the employee who's ID number is lesser between the two, and omits the other employee from the lists.  The question is, how do I fix it, and if this code has to be fixed my employee file?  Here is my Employee code.  Any tip/links/advice is helpful.

```
public class Employee implements Comparable {
private String firstName; 
private String lastName;
private int id;
private int perfScale;

Employee() {
firstName = "";
lastName = "";
id = 0;
perfScale = 0;
}

Employee(String lastName, String firstName, int id, int perfScale){
this.firstName = firstName;
this.lastName = lastName;
this.id = id;
this.perfScale = perfScale;
}
public String getLastName() {
return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName){
this.lastName = lastName;
}
public String getFirstName() {
return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName){
this.firstName = firstName;
}
public int getId() {
return id;
}
public void setId(int id){
this.id = id;
}
public int getPerfScale() {
return perfScale;
}
public void setPerfScale(int perfScale){
this.perfScale = perfScale;
}
public boolean equals(Object o) {
if(o instanceof Employee)
    return(getLastName() == ((Employee) o) .getLastName()) &&
        (getFirstName() == ((Employee)o) .getFirstName());
else
    return false;
}

public int compareTo(Object o) {
Employee e = (Employee) o;
int performance1 = e.getPerfScale();
int performance2 = this.getPerfScale();

if(performance1 < performance2) {
    return 1;

} else if(performance1 > performance2) {
    return -1;
} else {
    return this.getLastName().compareTo(e.getLastName());
}
}

public int hashCode() {
int h1 = firstName.hashCode();
int h2 = lastName.hashCode();
int h3 = new Integer(id).hashCode();
final int HASH_MULTIPLIER1 = 29;
final int HASH_MULTIPLIER2 = 19;
final int HASH_MULTIPLIER3 = 17;
int h = HASH_MULTIPLIER1 * h1 + HASH_MULTIPLIER2 * h2 + HASH_MULTIPLIER3 * h3;
return h;
}

public String toString()
{
    return getLastName() + ", " + getFirstName() + " ," + getId() + " rating: " +     getPerfScale()+ " Performance Scale";

}
    }
```

Now here is just my code for the case that deals with sorting by ascending name.  The whole code is longer than the code I printed, so I'll just print the case where it produces the sorting.

```
public static void printLastNameAscending(TreeMap<String, Employee> LastName,
        TreeMap<Integer, Employee>idNumber) {
    Set Employee1 = LastName.entrySet();
    Set Employee2 = idNumber.entrySet();
    Iterator itr1 = Employee1.iterator();
    Iterator itr2 = Employee2.iterator();

    while (itr1.hasNext() && itr2.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry) itr1.next();
        Map.Entry be = (Map.Entry) itr2.next();
        System.out.print(me.getKey()+ " ID: ");
        System.out.println(be.getKey());
    }

}
```

Comment: From your `compareTo` code it does not seem that you are sorting by last name first but by performance. You should also use Generics, so `implements Comparable<Employee>` rather than the raw `Comparable` - your compiler should warn you about that unless you have warnings turned off; which is usually not a good idea.

Comment: Ok, i'll change my comparable to generics.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I'll also look into the compareTo method as well.  Thanks for the reply.  Edit: Thanks Boris & ljgw, i'll check both the problems.

Comment: If you want it to sort by those three properties, you need to write code that compares by those properties.  (which you didn't)

Comment: as an added tip: it's good coding practice to make sure your objects are not null when comparing / checking for equality. Defensive coding can and will aid you in reducing (the risc of) NullPointerExceptions. (the occurrance which in my case used to mean getting coffee for the team;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem though, is if the two employees has the same first name as well, then it has to sort by ID number, which does not.

Your `compareTo` doesn't do anything with the ID number nor with the first name. In fact, it uses the performance first.

> My code: If two employee have the same full name but different ID number, then it only prints out the employee who's ID number is lesser between the two, and omits the other employee from the lists. The question is, how do I fix it, and if this code has to be fixed my employee file? Here is my Employee code. Any tip/links/advice is helpful.

Look at your `equals` function for the problem: Your map thinks that two employees are the same if the first and last names are the same. You should rewrite your `equals` function to also take the employeeID into account.

Comment: Ok, I will reexamine my equals function, and fix it asap.  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Not sure `equals` has a lot to do with it if its a `TreeMap`. This is a very valid point however - `compareTo` should be "consistent with `equals`".

Comment: yes, I agree there is more than just the (for me eye-catching) problem with equals.